# Capistrano sempre sobreescreve config/routes.rb para o código padrão do rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bom dia galera!

Estou com o seguinte problema: Sempre que executo `cap production deploy`, o Capistrano sobreescreve o **routes.rb** com o código padrão do rails.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Não importa o quanto eu altere em cada deploy, ele sempre vai estar com esse mesmo conteúdo.

Alguém tem idéia do que possa ser?

Desde já agradeço!

**GemFile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano3-nginx'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'highline'
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**CapFile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/nginx'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.6.1'

set :application, 'demo-ror'
set :repo_url, '<my_git_repo>'
set :scm, :git
set :branch, :master
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/demo-ror'
set :tmp_dir, '/home/ubuntu/tmp'
set :pty, true
set :format, :airbrussh
set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: 'log/capistrano.log', color: :auto, truncate: :auto
set :keep_releases, 5
set :keep_assets, 2
set :app_server, true
set :app_server_host, "127.0.0.1"
set :app_server_port, 8080

# nginx
set :nginx_sudo_paths, [:nginx_sites_enabled_dir, :nginx_sites_available_dir]
set :nginx_domains, "<my_domain>"
set :nginx_service_path, "service nginx"
set :nginx_roles, :web
set :nginx_log_path, "#{shared_path}/log"
set :nginx_static_dir, "public"
set :nginx_application_name, "#{fetch(:application)}"
set :nginx_sites_available_dir, "/etc/nginx/sites-available"
set :nginx_sites_enabled_dir, "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled"
set :nginx_template, :default
set :nginx_use_ssl, false
set :nginx_ssl_certificate, "#{fetch(:application)}.crt"
set :nginx_ssl_certificate_path, "/etc/ssl/certs"
set :nginx_ssl_certificate_key, "#{fetch(:application)}.key"
set :nginx_ssl_certificate_key_path, "/etc/ssl/private"
set :nginx_read_timeout, 30

# puma
set :puma_user, fetch(:user)
set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
set :puma_default_control_app, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/pumactl.sock"
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 16]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, false
set :puma_preload_app, false
set :puma_plugins, []

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Comment: Ele altera localmente ou em produção?

Comment: Somente quando eu executo o **cap production deploy** o Capistrano substitui o **routes.rb** de **/var/www/demo-ror/current/config/routes.rb** e na pasta **releases** para o **routes.rb** padrão do rails. Localmente e no repositório, tudo normal.